# Rotating PIL Image does not seem to rotate canvas (no TKinter canvas added)

Tags: python, image-processing, rotation, python-imaging-library

I'm having an issue rotating an image I've created. Because the code is spread out amongst a number of methods, I have put what I think to be the pertinent commands below.

The issue is that while the image is created successfully, when I rotate it using the img.rotate(-90)...the image rotates, but it appears the pallet/background/canvas does not (see attached image).

How can I correct this. Do I need to create a larger transparent background? Can I get the background/canvas to rotate as well...or do I rotate and then resize the background/Canvas?

FIRST EXAMPLE IMAGE (QRCODE)

```
img = Image.new('RGB', (x,y), 'white')
qr = qrcode.QRCode(version=1,error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,box_size=10,border=1,)
qr.add_data('QRB.NO/AbCd1')
qr.make(fit=True)
QRimg = qr.make_image()
img = img.paste(QRimg, (x,y))
img.show() #333
raw_input('(Above is unrotated QRcode image) Press enter...') #333
img = img.rotate(-90)
print img, type(img)
img.show() #333
raw_input('Above is the rotated -90 QRcode image. Press enter...') #333
```

SECOND EXAMPLE IMAGE

```
font_name      = 'Arial.ttf'
font_size      = 16 
font = ImageFont.truetype(font_name, font_size)
img = Image.new('RGB', (x,y), color=background_color)
# Place text 
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.text( (corner_X,corner_Y), 'QRB.NO/AbCd1', font=font, fill='#000000' ) 
draw.rectangle((0,0,x-1,y-1), outline = "black")
del draw
print img, type(img)
img.show() #333
raw_input('(Above is the unrotated test image). Press enter...') #333
img = img.rotate(90)
print img, type(img)
img.show() #333
raw_input('(Above is the ROTATED 90 text image). Press enter...') #333
```

OUTPUT

```
<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=71x57 at 0x10E9B8C10> <class 'PIL.Image.Image'>
(Above is unrotated QRcode image) Press enter...

<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=71x57 at 0x10E9B8F90> <class 'PIL.Image.Image'>
Above is the rotated -90 QRcode image. Press enter...

<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=57x9 at 0x10EA6CB90> <class 'PIL.Image.Image'>
(Above is the unrotated test image). Press enter...

<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=57x9 at 0x10E9B8C10> <class 'PIL.Image.Image'>
(Above is the ROTATED 90 text image). Press enter...
```

[image: Bad Rotations]

EDIT:

```
x,y = img.size
img = img.resize( (y, x),  Image.ANTIALIAS )
img = img.rotate(-90)
```

...or...

```
x,y = img.size
img = img.rotate(-90)
img = img.resize( (y, x),  Image.ANTIALIAS )
```

...don't seem to help.

[image: Trying resize and rotate]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Figured it out. I'm going to leave it up to help others, as this seems to be a subtle yet important difference.

```
img = img.transpose(Image.ROTATE_270)
```

...or...

```
img = img.transpose(Image.ROTATE_90)
```

[Docs](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.transpose)

Answer (score 7):

Use the optional `expand` flag in the rotate method:

`image.rotate(45, expand=True)`

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.rotate

Comment: no, it will leave black padding